# Howto examine return value from object function in a core?

Tags: c++, gdb, core-file

Example code:

```
struct Message {
   virtual int id() const { return 0; }
};
struct Ping : public Message {
   virtual int id() const { return 1; }
};
```

Suppose you have a core file loaded in gdb.
Here you have a Message * msg;
Are there a simple way to figure out what id function will return on msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "set print object on" to enable vtable inspection to print the derived type of objects.  This is so desirable for C++ that I've had it in my .gdbinit for 15 years.

You can't call the methods when using a core, of course, but you can then at least see the real type and look up the method yourself.

Comment: In a test it prints: _vptr.Message = 0x400b00 <vtable for Ping+16>}, _vptr.Message = 0x400ae0 <vtable for Message+16>